# How to add UserData to an AWS LaunchTemplate in AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have been using AWS CDK (Typescript) with several of my builds but I am finding it hard to add my bash script to the UserData of my `CfnLaunchTemplate`. An excerpt of my Launch
Template is like so:

```
    const bootscript = readFileSync('./scripts/test.sh', 'utf8');
    
      // Creation of launch template
      const launchTest = new ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(this, "launchTest", {
        launchTemplateData: {
          imageId: AMI-test.valueAsString,
          instanceType: "t3a.medium",
          //userData: bootscript,
          //securityGroups: [launchTestSG],
          keyName: props.privateKey,
          iamInstanceProfile: {
            name: props.iamProfile
          }
        },
        launchTemplateName: "LT-Example",
      })

    launchTest.userAddData(bootscript);
```

I would expect this to work which does not. I have looked at documentation detailing the issues of AWS CDK when it comes to Launch Templates so I went the route of using `CfnLaunchTemplates` but boy does it pose issues down the road. If anyone can assist me with I would appreciate it.

P.S: I'm also having issues in getting my new Security Group to be attached to the Launch Template as well. The error I get like so:

```
Type 'SecurityGroup' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Thanks for anyone on helping me with this!

UPDATE: This update is in regards to the part where I imported the VPC for my Security Group to be made:

```
  let vpcDB = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "InfraJumpVPC", {
    vpcId: props.vpcId,
    availabilityZones: ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"],
  });

  // Create a security group for launchTest:
  const launchTestSG = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, "launchTestSG", {
    vpc: vpcDB,
    allowAllOutbound: true,
    description: "Security group for Testing web server"
  })
```

Sorry, just updated the code for a misplaced Security Group.

Comment: What exactly is `sg-test`?

Comment: It's the Security Group. Let me add more information on the Security Group since I imported my VPC Id then created a Security Group.

Comment: Thanks for edit but its still not shown what is `sg-test`?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error or just an expected result?

Comment: The `bootscript` (which houses the UserData for the Launch Template) does not work with `CfnLaunchTemplate`. So the original question is how to add your bash script into the User Data for a Launch Template.

Comment: When you say does not work, do you mean that the stack fails to create or the user data fails to run when the instance starts up? If the stack fails to create, is there an error?

Comment: @Roma did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Use the L2 `LaunchTemplate` construct, it's easier to use. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.LaunchTemplate.html), `userData` accepts an instance of [`ec2.UserData`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.UserData.html). A simple example of userData:

Excuse me if I get any TS syntax wrong, I write in Python:

```js
const my_userdata = UserData.forLinux();
my_userdata.addCommands(["echo hello", "ls ."]);
```